Будет ли VS code читать файлы, написанные в PyCharm?
Я хочу перейти от PyCharm к VS Code, но не уверен, будут ли мои проекты, написанные на PyCharm работать в VS Code?

да. будет. он конечно не прочитает настройки языка для проекта - создаст свои. но сам код прочитается.
